# or die('mysql_error())) not showing an error, but the die is actioning and the query still works

Tags: php, mysql

I could ignore this but would rather find out why it not acting as I imagine.

I have this query:

```
$updateQuery = $mysqli->query(
    "UPDATE `enquiries`
    SET `customer_id` = '$customer_id'
    WHERE `email` = '$email'"
) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
```

After this query I simply echo out

```
 echo "Query Complete";
```

The query is only part of a longer script, before I added this query the Query Complete message was echoed out.

After adding this query nothing was shown. So I added the:

```
or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
```

To debug but it simply shows 'Error:' and not any errors. My question is that the query itself actually runs fine, and updates the rows as neeeded but it kills the script still.

Where am I going wrong with this? Thanks.

Comment: You're mixing up mysql and mysqli.

Comment: And since you're using the object-oriented interface, you need to use `$mysqli->error` to get the last error.

Comment: `mysql_error` can only give you errors for connections established via `mysql_*`. You're using mysqli. They're completely different things.

Comment: An an aside: don't use `die` for error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up `mysql` and `mysqli`, which obviously won't work, in your case you were looking for `mysqli_error` but even then it won't work because you use the object-oriented interface.

Use `$mysqli->error` to access the last error string, as described in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.error.php).